# Error and exception handling in php7

Tags: php, error-handling, exception

Recently moved to php7. The following error occurs:

```
argument 1 passed to MyClass\Throwable::exceptionHandler() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given
```

And the respective class

```
namespace MyClass;

class Throwable
{
    public function exceptionHandler(\Exception $exception)
    {
        //logic here
    }
}
```

As stated in [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php)

> most errors are now reported by throwing Error exceptions.

Does it mean that I have to provide an instance of `Error` or even more general `Throwable` to the exception handler?

Comment: have a look at https://trowski.com/2015/06/24/throwable-exceptions-and-errors-in-php7/ it might help you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Errors` and `Exceptions` both extend `Throwable` however Errors are not extended from `Exception`.

Therefore, your ExceptionHandler must accept an object of Type `Throwable` in order to accept `Errors`.

Simplest fix is this, though you may want to rename $exception to make it clear.

```
namespace MyClass;

class Throwable
{
    public function exceptionHandler(\Throwable $exception)
    {
        //logic here
    }
}
```

Note: The new `Error` class should not be confussed with an `ErrorException` which has classicly been used as a device for turning PHP 5 errors into `Exception` objects with symantic meaning.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php

Comment: Both `Errors` and `Exceptions` are children of `Throwable`; ok, if I switched to your solution what could be the difference between `Error` and `Exception`? And `set_exception_handler` now provides object of `Error` ? Then what are `Exception` meant for and how are they handled?

Comment: If you want to specifically handle an Exception and not an Error you could always do `if ($throwable instanceof \Exception) { ... }`. I'm curious as to why you'd want to deal with them differently at that point though? :)

Comment: you're right. This would be the preferable solution.